# INSERT multiple rows not working SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

This seems like a silly question, but has been driving me crazy. The title pretty much says it: I cannot insert multiple rows into my table.

Here's the relevant code:

```
create table ##temp (
no1 int,
no2 int
)

insert into ##temp (no1,no2)
values 
(1,2), 
(3,4)
```

The error is

```
Incorrect syntax near ','
```

which is the comma between (1,2) and (3,4)

Hope somebody can help. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, by the way. Thanks..

Comment: this seems to be working for me .. .but I have a newer version of SQL Server

Comment: Compatibility mode??

Comment: Are you **sure** that you're running against a **2008 R2** engine?? What does `SELECT @@VERSION` say? Do you maybe have multiple instances on your machine, and using the **2008 R2** Management Studio, you're really trying this against a 2005 instance?

Comment: Sqlserver 2008 R2 support this type of syntax. so give the marc answer as above.

Comment: Okay, the       SELECT @@VERSION      tells me that the instance is 2005. Thanks guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into ##temp (no1,no2)
select 1, 2
union select 3, 4
```